# Basic shell that takes multiple word command

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to implement a shell that takes a command ; however, I can not get it to work properly. For example, if I type "ls -a", I get this:

invalid option -- '
'

Try 'ls --help' for more information.

I have probably made some bad mistakes as I am a beginner so please forgive me. Also, I will put the code that reads in the command into a function. Its just like this for testing- thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t       pid;
    int         status;
    char* token;
    char* argv[20];
    char input[100];

    printf("AP> ");

    while (1)
    {
        fgets(input, 100, stdin);
        token = strtok(input, " ");

        int i = 0;
        //walk through other tokens
        while (token != NULL) {
            argv[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strncpy(argv[i], token, strlen(token));
            //argv[i] = token;
            i++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        argv[i] = NULL; //argv ends with NULL

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork error");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            // child process
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            perror("execl error");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        else {
            // parent process
            if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0)<0)
            {
                perror("waitpid error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        printf("AP> ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert the following loop after the inner while loop, then you'll see that you aren't removing the newline character at the end of `input` before the while loop starts.

```
for (i=0; argv[i]; i++)
   printf("argv[%d] = '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
" \n"
```

as your separators instead of just

```
" "
```